Implementing OpenTelemetry Collector as Windows Service with Go
I found an example on how to run a Windows executable as a service using Go in the github.com/golang/sys repository. The example is available at https://github.com/golang/sys/blob/master/windows/svc/example/service.go. Now, I want to modify this example to run my OpenTelemetry Collector as a service. Where should I integrate my OpenTelemetry Collector code within this Go service implementation?
Here's the Go code snippet I'm referring to:
func main() {
    inService, err := svc.IsWindowsService()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("failed to determine if we are running in service: %v", err)
    }
    if inService {
        service.RunService(svcName)
        return
    }
    
    err = service.InstallService(svcName, "vcoa")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("failed to install the service: %v", err)
    }
    
    err = service.StartService(svcName)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("failed to start the service: %v", err)
    }
}

func exePath() (string, error) {
    prog := os.Args[0]
    p, err := filepath.Abs(prog)
    if err != nil {
        return "", err
    }
    fi, err := os.Stat(p)
    if err == nil {
        if !fi.Mode().IsDir() {
            return p, nil
        }
        err = fmt.Errorf("%s is directory", p)
    }
    if filepath.Ext(p) == "" {
        p += ".exe"
        fi, err := os.Stat(p)
        if err == nil {
            if !fi.Mode().IsDir() {
                return p, nil
            }
            err = fmt.Errorf("%s is directory", p)
        }
    }
    return "", err
}

func InstallService(name, desc string) error {
    exepath, err := exePath()
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    m, err := mgr.Connect()
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    defer m.Disconnect()
    s, err := m.OpenService(name)
    if err == nil {
        s.Close()
        return fmt.Errorf("service %s already exists", name)
    }
    s, err = m.CreateService(name, exepath, mgr.Config{DisplayName: desc})
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    defer s.Close()
    err = eventlog.InstallAsEventCreate(name, eventlog.Error|eventlog.Warning|eventlog.Info)
    if err != nil {
        s.Delete()
        return fmt.Errorf("SetupEventLogSource() failed: %s", err)
    }
    return nil
}

func StartService(name string) error {
    m, err := mgr.Connect()
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    defer m.Disconnect()
    s, err := m.OpenService(name)
    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("could not access service: %v", err)
    }
    defer s.Close()
    err = s.Start()
    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("could not start service: %v", err)
    }
    return nil
}

func (m *myService) Execute(args []string, r <-chan svc.ChangeRequest, changes chan<- svc.Status) (ssec bool, errno uint32) {
    const cmdsAccepted = svc.AcceptStop | svc.AcceptShutdown | svc.AcceptPauseAndContinue
    changes <- svc.Status{State: svc.StartPending}
    changes <- svc.Status{State: svc.Running, Accepts: cmdsAccepted}

loop:
    for {
        select {
        case c := <-r:
            log.Printf("Received service change request: %+v", c)
            switch c.Cmd {
            case svc.Interrogate:
                changes <- c.CurrentStatus
                time.Sleep(100 * time.Millisecond)
                changes <- c.CurrentStatus
            case svc.Stop, svc.Shutdown:
                break loop
            case svc.Pause:
                changes <- svc.Status{State: svc.Paused, Accepts: cmdsAccepted}
            case svc.Continue:
                changes <- svc.Status{State: svc.Running, Accepts: cmdsAccepted}
            default:
                elog.Error(1, fmt.Sprintf("unexpected control request #%d", c))
            }
        }
    }
    changes <- svc.Status{State: svc.StopPending}
    return
}

func RunService(name string) {
    err := debug.Run(name, &myService{})
    if err != nil {
        elog.Error(1, fmt.Sprintf("%s service failed: %v", name, err))
        return
    }
    elog.Info(1, fmt.Sprintf("%s service stopped", name))
}

I attempted to adapt a Go example for running a Windows executable as a service to incorporate my OpenTelemetry Collector.
